# Table ordering Cucumber Capybara

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'm writing some tests for a web app, I'm still pretty new to this Cucumber Capybara.

I've got a table of data on screen which can be ordered ascending/descending by clicking on the column header.

I've created a hash out of the headers using:

```
 table_head = find('#clickable-rows > thead')
   headers = Hash.new(table_head)
```

In total there are seven headers on the table, I'd like to click on any of them by referencing the index (0 - 6).

I've tried

```
find(headers[0]).click
```

All of the other click commands referencing the header in that way and I keep getting the error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I'm clearly missing a trick here, does anyone have a solution or better way to do this? I thought hashing would be the most suitable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`headers` is not likely what you expect. Unless I am missing something, it will be an empty `Hash`. Given you just want to click one of the column headers by index, you just need to locate the element and click it. There should not be a need to create a `Hash`.

Assuming that the clickable part of the column headers are links, the following returns all of the header elements:

```
column_headers = all('#clickable-rows > thead a')
```

You can then click one based on its position:

```
column_headers[0].click
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Again, getting confused by the basics.  Thank you